# How to import functions from different file and use in discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

A straight Forward question - How to import a function from a different file and use that in discord.py cuz i tried that and failed for example there is file a and b which looks like
a.py:

```
async def joke(ctx):
   joke = 'Your mama so fat boy'
   await ctx.send(joke)
```

and i want to use the joke function from file a to file b and the code i write was:

```
from a import joke
from discord.ext import commands
#some discord code
TOKEN = 'My_Secret_Token'
GUILD = 'My_Guild'
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
@client.command(name='joke', help='This will return a joke')
joke()
client.run(TOKEN)
```

And the line joke() is returning me error

```
  File "main.py", line 31
    joke()
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And i am here confused that why it is returning me error and how can i pass the argument ctx. So please come up with a solution for me.

Edit: After debugging and scratching my head for hours i came up with a solution which is also not working that i modified my b.py a little bit :

```
from a import joke
from discord.ext import commands
#some discord code
TOKEN = 'My_Secret_Token'
GUILD = 'My_Guild'
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
@client.command(name='joke', help='This will return a joke')
async def my_function(ctx):
    joke(ctx)
client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: use `cogs` for this.read more here: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/cogs.html

Comment: You use async def to define the joke function so you supposed to call it with await like this: ``await joke(ctx)``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cogs for this. Docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/cogs.html
Here is an Example:
`Your main.py`

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

for file in os.listdir("cogs"):
    if file.endswith(".py"):
        name = file[:-3]
        client.load_extension(f"cogs.{name}")


client.run(TOKEN)
```

Make a secound `/cogs/joke.py`

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random

class joke(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def joke(self, ctx):
        jokes = [
        'Your mama so fat boy',
        'joke2',
        'joke3',
        'joke4',
        'joke5'
        ]
        answer = random.choice(jokes)
        await ctx.send(answer)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(joke(bot))
```